# Gujarati fonts not displaying in PDF properly using itext 5.5.5 and xmlworker 5.5.5

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext, substitution, xmlworker

I am using arial .ttf file. I have tried different font file for gujarati such as lohit, padmaa, shruti but it not displaying properly. The characters are not getting substituted properly.

In PDF it displays as :

> અરથ પરજ ડરમ વૈભવ સવગે

Originally it should display as:

> અર્થ પ્રજા ડ્રમ વૈભવ સ્વર્ગે

I have tried using `GlyphSubstitutionTableReader` but its not working for me.

Please guide me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

iText 5 currently doesn't support any Brahmic scripts. The reason is that these require an implementation of a specific font table called GSUB, which simply isn't there yet. There is no way to get this to display correctly with iText 5.5.5, but anyone is welcome to try and implement it.